# Losing control of GUI upon playing a wav file

Tags: python

I can't understand why I am loosing control of my GUI even though I am implementing a thread to play a .wav file. Can someone pin point what is incorrect?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import wx, pyaudio, wave, easygui, thread, time, os, sys, traceback, threading
import wx.lib.delayedresult as inbg

isPaused = False
isStopped = False

class Frame(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(self):
            print 'Frame'
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title="Jasmine", size=(720, 300))

            #initialize panel
            panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

            #initialize grid bag
            sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=20, vgap=20) 

            #initialize buttons
            exitButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Exit")
            pauseButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Pause')
            prevButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Prev')
            nextButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Next')
            stopButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Stop')

            #add widgets to sizer
            sizer.Add(pauseButton, pos=(1,10))
            sizer.Add(prevButton, pos=(1,11))
            sizer.Add(nextButton, pos=(1,12))
            sizer.Add(stopButton, pos=(1,13))
            sizer.Add(exitButton, pos=(5,13))

            #initialize song time gauge
            #timeGauge = wx.Gauge(panel, 20)
            #sizer.Add(timeGauge, pos=(3,10), span=(0, 0))

            #initialize menuFile widget
            menuFile = wx.Menu()
            menuFile.Append(0, "L&oad")
            menuFile.Append(1, "E&xit")
            menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
            menuBar.Append(menuFile, "&File")
            menuAbout = wx.Menu()
            menuAbout.Append(2, "A&bout...")
            menuAbout.AppendSeparator()
            menuBar.Append(menuAbout, "Help")
            self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
            self.CreateStatusBar()
            self.SetStatusText("Welcome to Jasime!")

            #place sizer on panel
            panel.SetSizer(sizer)

            #initialize icon
            self.cd_image = wx.Image('cd_icon.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
            self.temp = self.cd_image.ConvertToBitmap()
            self.size = self.temp.GetWidth(), self.temp.GetHeight()
            wx.StaticBitmap(parent=panel, bitmap=self.temp)

  #set binding
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, id=exitButton.GetId())
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pause, id=pauseButton.GetId())
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.stop, id=stopButton.GetId())
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.loadFile, id=0)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=1)  
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, id=2)

 #Load file using FileDialog, and create a thread for user control while running the file 
 def loadFile(self, event):

  foo = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Open a .wav file...", defaultDir=os.getcwd(), defaultFile="", style=wx.FD_MULTIPLE)
  foo.ShowModal()

  self.queue = foo.GetPaths()
  self.threadID = 1  

  while len(self.queue) != 0:
   self.song = myThread(self.threadID, self.queue[0])
   self.song.start()
   while self.song.isAlive():
    time.sleep(2)
   self.queue.pop(0)
                self.threadID += 1

 def OnQuit(self, event):
  self.Close()

 def OnAbout(self, event):
  wx.MessageBox("This is a great cup of tea.", "About Jasmine", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION, self)

 def pause(self, event):
  global isPaused
  isPaused = not isPaused

 def stop(self, event):
  global isStopped
  isStopped = not isStopped


class myThread (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, wf):
   self.threadID = threadID
   self.wf = wf
   threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  def run(self):
   global isPaused
   global isStopped  

   self.waveFile = wave.open(self.wf, 'rb')         

   #initialize stream
   self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
   self.stream = self.p.open(format = self.p.get_format_from_width(self.waveFile.getsampwidth()), channels = self.waveFile.getnchannels(), rate = self.waveFile.getframerate(), output = True)
   self.data = self.waveFile.readframes(1024)

   isPaused = False
   isStopped = False
   #main play loop, with pause event checking
   while self.data != '':
   # while isPaused != True:
   #  if isStopped == False:
     self.stream.write(self.data)
     self.data = self.waveFile.readframes(1024)
   #  elif isStopped == True:
   #   self.stream.close()
   #   self.p.terminate()

   self.stream.close()
   self.p.terminate()

class App(wx.App):

 def OnInit(self):
  self.frame = Frame()
  self.frame.Show()
  self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
  return True

def main():
 app = App()
 app.MainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: Next time (or even this time) please create a concise sample of code that reproduces your problem exactly. Almost every time you do this, you'll end up solving the problem yourself. If you don't, it makes it significantly easier for someone else to help.

Comment: I'd also recommend you to write a more specific title.

Answer (score 2):

Your `loadFile` method, quite independently of the fact that it delegates song-playing to many threads (which it waits for in strange ways, but, that's another issue), is **still** monopolizing the wx event loop until it returns.  Where you currently have a `time.sleep`, try adding `app.Yield(True)` (of course you need to make `app` visible at that point in your code: simplest though inelegant is to add a `global app` at the start of `main`.

Event-driven systems typically serve the event loop only when your various event handler methods return: if you have a long-running event handler, you need to explicitly yield control to the event loop once in a while.  Various event systems offer different ways to do it: in `wx`, it's the `Yield` method which I just recommended you try.  See the brief description un [the docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PyApp-class.html).